# change event is not fired on Microsoft Edge on first click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement drag and drop and browse files. I have a `<div>` with id `#box` and trying to trigger `<input type="file" id="imageUpload" />` on click event of that `<div>`. The following code is working fine on Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome but having problem on **Microsoft Edge**.

```js
$(document).off().on('click', '#box', function () {
    $('#imageUpload').trigger('click');
    $('#imageUpload').off().on('change', function () {                        
        var imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageUpload');
        selectedFiles = imageLoader.files;
        imageBrowseUploader(selectedFiles);
    });
});
```

```css
#box {
    border: 1px dotted #0B85A1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    color: #92AAB0;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 500;
}

#imageUpload {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">
    <b>Drag and drop or click here</b> to upload your image.
</div>
<input type="file" id="imageUpload" />
```

Comment: `trigger('click')` after binding event. Why are you binding event handler inside another event handler?

Comment: Share your #imageUpload function click

Comment: Because I need <input type="file" id="imageUpload" /> triggered when <div id="box">
                <b>Drag and drop or click here</b>
                to upload your image.
            </div> is clicked.

Comment: @SilverSurfer #imageUpload is the id of <input>

Comment: Input type? Try share at least an example of your html to help you

Comment: This is my html I am trying to open browse file on div click.<div id="box">
                <b>Drag and drop or click here</b>
                to upload your image.
            </div>
            <input type="file" id="imageUpload" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put the on change outside the click function, like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).off().on('click', '#box', function () {
      $('#imageUpload').trigger('click');
   });
   $('#imageUpload').off().on('change', function () {
      var imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageUpload');
      selectedFiles = imageLoader.files;
      imageBrowseUploader(selectedFiles);
   });
});
```

```css
#box {
    border: 1px dotted #0B85A1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    color: #92AAB0;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 500;
}

#imageUpload {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">
  <b>Drag and drop or click here</b> to upload your image.
 </div> 
 <input type="file" id="imageUpload" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working Demo with minor changes! (As you can see)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(document).on('click', '#box', function () {
  //debugger;
  $('#imageUpload').trigger('click');
 });
 
 $(document).on('change', function () {  
  debugger;
  var imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageUpload');
  selectedFiles = imageLoader.files[0].name;
  imageBrowseUploader(selectedFiles);
 });
});

function imageBrowseUploader(selectedFiles)
{
 alert(selectedFiles);
}
```

```css
#box {
    border: 1px dotted #0B85A1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    color: #92AAB0;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 500;
}

#imageUpload {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="box">
  <b>Drag and drop or click here</b> to upload your image.
 </div>
 <input type="file" id="imageUpload" />
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this will works for you! thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).off().on('click', '#box', function () {
    $('#imageUpload').trigger('click');
    $('#imageUpload').off().on('change', function () {                        
        var imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageUpload');
        selectedFiles = imageLoader.files;
        imageBrowseUploader(selectedFiles);
    });
});
```

```css
#box {
    border: 1px dotted #0B85A1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    color: #92AAB0;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 500;
}

#imageUpload {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">
  <b>Drag and drop or click here</b> to upload your image.
 </div>
 <input type="file" id="imageUpload" />
```

Your above function contains event inside event.Please don't do that and initialize your change function  inside document.ready function()